# ngmodelchange called when mat-option selected in angular material

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, angular6

I have a scenario whenever the user starts searching for something which will call the HTTP service and get the response and show it in the dropdown.

I have the below code which is working fine with the above approach. But, after we click any option listed from the dropdown, `ngmodelchange` method again calling which fetch the service again. It should not happen.

Where am I missing?

```
<mat-form-field class="half-width">
            <input matInput aria-label="State" name="state" placeholder="Search by number (1 or 2 or 3)" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [(ngModel)]="currentState"
              (ngModelChange) = "filterInstrument(currentState)">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="state">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let state of insDetails" [value]="state.id">
                  <span>{{state.id}}</span> |
                  <span>{{state.userId}}</span> |
                  <span>{{state.title}}</span>                 
                </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Complete Code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzcvyw-zaap11?file=app/select-multiple-example.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the (input) event instead of the (ngModelChange)

Explanation :

> The "input" event, is a synchronous event
>   that is triggered as the user is interacting with the text-based input
>   controls. Meaning, it doesn't wait for a blur event to calculate the
>   value-change - the input event is triggered immediately after any
>   mutation of the value property (whether it be through user key-stroke
>   events or user paste events).

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the `ngModelChange` event to `keypress` event

```
<mat-form-field class="half-width">
            <input matInput aria-label="State" name="state" placeholder="Search by number (1 or 2 or 3)" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [(ngModel)]="currentState"
              (keypress) = "filterInstrument(currentState)">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="state">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let state of insDetails" [value]="state.id">
                  <span>{{state.id}}</span> |
                  <span>{{state.userId}}</span> |
                  <span>{{state.title}}</span>                 
                </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
          </mat-form-field>
```

> **ngModelChange** gets called if there is a change in the input value but the **keypress** event gets called once you type any value

Comment: if I use keypress, cannot capture ngmodel value

Comment: (input) event is better for a delete event